# React ignores one of two style classes

Tags: css, reactjs

Two buttons are rendered in my button component. Depending on the label, the button receives the class addButton or clearButton.

Button Component:

```
import './Button.css'

interface ButtonProps {
    lable: string,
    disabled: boolean,
    onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>    
}

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ lable, disabled, onClick}): ReactElement => {
    
    
    let style: string = lable == 'ADD' ? 'addButton' : 'clearButton';
    console.log(lable);
    
    console.log(style);
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button className= {`button ${style}`} type='button' disabled= { disabled } onClick= { onClick }>
                {lable}
            </button>   
        </div>     
    );
}
```

In the stylesheet Button.css are the two classes addButton and clearButton. Strangely, only the style class that is in second place is loaded. In this situation, the addButton receives its colour and the clearButton remains colourless. If I place the style class of the clearButton in second place in the stylesheet, it receives its colour and the addButton remains colourless.

Button.css

```
.clearButton {
    background-color: #8c00ff;
}


.addButton {
    background-color: #7ce0ff;
   
}
```

If I outsource both style classes to separate stylesheets, it works but this is not an elegant solution.

I would also like to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've execute your code, and it works, I think the problem is where you call the button you are not passing props to

Answer (score 0):

change import type of button style

```
import styles from './Button.css';

return(
        <div>
            <button className={`button ${label === 'ADD' ? styles.addButton : styles.clearButton}`}>
                {lable}
            </button>   
        </div>     
    );
```

and reolace background-color to background

```
.clearButton {
    background: #8c00ff;
}


.addButton {
    background: #7ce0ff;
   
}
```

you can test code in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q85v52p3m4) project

Comment: Thank you fpr the Answer. I got an Error at the way you import the Button (import styles from './Button.css') ERROR: Cannot find module './Button.css' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: @eaP4D Are you sure you have the Button.css file in same folder? If your answer is yes, change the file to Button.module.css and change`  import styles from './Button.module.css' ` in button component